# Unable to run any Video File Format

Tags: 12.04, video-player

Whenever i try to run any Video File in my ubuntu system Movie Player it asks for plugins installations as shown below

[image]

But after i click on install button it gives an error that the package dependencies couldn't be resolved.

[image]

Comment: Read the answer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/a/162151/53498.  Also go to Ubuntu Software Centre and intall "Ubuntu Restricted Extras"  Once you do this your issue will be resolved.

Comment: Please provide the details of the error message.

Comment: Im sure this question is a duplicate, having trouble finding the original though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type Following commands in terminal. (Press ctrl+alt+t to open)

```
 sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will fix package dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

This will install necessary Codecs to play media files.

Comment: @KK can you please explain the option -f .. i couldn't find it in man pages !

Comment: when you use -f with install, it will automatically check dependencies and find out which packages are missing, then  it downloads missing packages and installs